# How to disable the past date from my calender?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I wanted to disable the past date from my calender , i went with some articles . but nothing will help much .

**here is my code**

```
  import('form.FormElement');
  import('DateAndTime');

  class Calendar extends FormElement {
var $holidays = array();
var $showHolidays = true;
var $weekStartDay = 0;

var $mHeader = "padding: 5px; font-size: 8pt; color: #333333; background-color: #d9d9d9;";
var $mDayCell = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid silver; font-size: 8pt; color: #333333; background-color: #ffffff;";
var $mDaySelected = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid silver; font-size: 8pt; color: #666666; background-color: #a6ccf7;";
var $mDayWeekend = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid silver; font-size: 8pt; color: #666666; background-color: #f7f7f7;";
var $mDayHoliday = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid silver; font-size: 8pt; color: #666666; background-color: #f7f7f7;";
var $mDayHeader = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8pt; color: #333333;";
var $mDayHeaderWeekend = "padding: 5px; border: 1px solid white; font-size: 8pt; color: #999999;";

var $controlName = "";
var $highlight = "time"; // Determines what type of active days to highlight ("time" or "expenses"). 
// var $mAllDays       = true;
var $cClassName    = "Calendar";

function __construct($name) {
    $this->controlName = $name;
    $this->mMonthNames = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
    $this->mWeekDayShortNames = array('Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa');
}

function setHighlight($highlight) {
    if ($highlight && $highlight != 'time')
      $this->highlight = $highlight;
}

function setLocalization($i18n) {
  global $user;

  FormElement::setLocalization($i18n);
  $this->mMonthNames    = $i18n->monthNames;
  $this->mWeekDayShortNames = $i18n->weekdayShortNames;
  if (is_array($i18n->holidays)) {
    foreach ($i18n->holidays as $fday) {
      $date_a = explode("/",$fday); // format mm/dd
      $this->holidays[] = mktime(0,0,0, $date_a[0], $date_a[1], date("Y"));// + 7200;
    }
  }
  $this->weekStartDay = $user->week_start;
}

function setStyle($style) { $this->mStyle = $style; }
function setCellStyle($style) { $this->mCellStyle = $style; }
function setACellStyle($style) { $this->mACellStyle = $style; }
function setLinkStyle($style) { $this->mLinkStyle = $style; }

function setShowHolidays($value) {
  $this->showHolidays = $value;
}

/**
 * @return void
 * @param date
 * @desc Enter description here...
 */
function toString($date="") {
  global $i18n;

  $indate = $this->mValue;
  if (!$indate) $indate = strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT);

  if (!$this->isRenderable()) return "";

  //current year and month
  if ( strlen ( $indate ) > 0 ) {
    $indateObj = new DateAndTime(DB_DATEFORMAT, $indate);
    $thismonth = $indateObj->getMonth();
    $thisyear = $indateObj->getYear();
  } else {
    $thismonth = date("m");
    $thisyear = date("Y");
  }

  // next date, month, year
  $next = mktime ( 2, 0, 0, $thismonth + 1, 1, $thisyear );
  $nextyear = date ( "Y", $next );
  $nextmonth = date ( "m", $next );
  $nextdate = strftime (DB_DATEFORMAT, $next );

  // prev date, month, year
  $prev = mktime ( 2, 0, 0, $thismonth - 1, 1, $thisyear );
  $prevyear = date ( "Y", $prev );
  $prevmonth = date ( "m", $prev );
  $prevdate = strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT, $prev );

  $str = $this->_genStyles();

  $str .= '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr><td align="center"><div class="CalendarHeader">'.
      //'<a href="?date='.$prevyear.'">&lt;&lt;</a> '.
      '<a href="?date='.$prevdate.'" tabindex="-1">&lt;&lt;&lt;</a>  '.
      $this->mMonthNames[$thismonth-1].'&nbsp;'.$thisyear.
      '  <a href="?date='.$nextdate.'" tabindex="-1">&gt;&gt;&gt;</a>'.
      //' <a href="?date='.$nextyear.'">&gt;&gt;</a>'.
      '</div></td></tr>
      </table>';

  $str .= '<center>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
      <tr>';

  $str .= "<tr>";

  $weekend_start = 6 - $this->weekStartDay;      // Saturday by default.
  $weekend_end = (7 - $this->weekStartDay) % 7;  // Sunday by default.
  if (defined('WEEKEND_START_DAY')) {
    $weekend_start = (7 + WEEKEND_START_DAY - $this->weekStartDay) % 7;
    $weekend_end = (7 + WEEKEND_START_DAY + 1 - $this->weekStartDay) % 7;
  } 

  for ( $i=0; $i<7; $i++ ) {
    $weekdayNameIdx = ($i + $this->weekStartDay) % 7;
    if ($i==$weekend_start || $i==$weekend_end) {
      $str .= '<td class="CalendarDayHeaderWeekend">'.$this->mWeekDayShortNames[$weekdayNameIdx].'</td>';
    } else {
      $str .= '<td class="CalendarDayHeader">'.$this->mWeekDayShortNames[$weekdayNameIdx].'</td>';
    }
  }

  $str .= "</tr>\n";

  list($wkstart,$monthstart,$monthend,$start_date) = $this->_getWeekDayBefore( $thisyear, $thismonth );

  $active_dates = $this->_getActiveDates($monthstart, $monthend);

  for ( $i = $wkstart; $i<=$monthend;  $i=mktime(0,0,0,$thismonth,$start_date+=7,$thisyear) ) {
    $str .= "<TR>\n";
      for ( $j = 0; $j < 7; $j++ ) {
        $date = mktime(0,0,0,$thismonth,$start_date+$j,$thisyear);
        if (($date >= $monthstart) && ($date <= $monthend)) {

        $stl_cell = "";
        $stl_link = "";

        // weekend
        if ($j==$weekend_start || $j==$weekend_end) {
          $stl_cell = ' class="CalendarDayWeekend"';
          $stl_link = ' class="CalendarLinkWeekend"';
        } else {
          $stl_cell = ' class="CalendarDay"';
        }

          // holidays
          if ($this->showHolidays) {
          foreach ($this->holidays as $day) {
            if($day == $date) {
              $stl_cell = ' class="CalendarDayHoliday"';
              $stl_link = ' class="CalendarLinkHoliday"';
            }
          }
        }

        // selected day
        if ( $indate == strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT, $date))
          $stl_cell = ' class="CalendarDaySelected"';


        $str .= '<td'.$stl_cell.'>';

        // Entries exist.
        if($active_dates) {
          if( in_array(strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT, $date), $active_dates) )
            $stl_link = ' class="CalendarLinkRecordsExist"';
        }

        $str .= "<a".$stl_link." href=\"?".$this->controlName."=".strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT, $date)."\" tabindex=\"-1\">".date("d",$date)."</a>";

        $str .= "</TD>";
      }
      else {
        $str .= "<TD>&nbsp;</TD>\n";
      }
    }
    $str .= "</TR>\n";
  }

  $str .= "<tr><td colspan=\"7\" align=\"center\"><a id=\"today_link\" href=\"?".$this->controlName."=".strftime(DB_DATEFORMAT)."\" tabindex=\"-1\">".$i18n->getKey('label.today')."</a></td></tr>\n";
  $str .= "</table>\n";

  $str .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$this->controlName\" value=\"$indate\">\n";

  // Add script to adjust today link to match browser today, as PHP may run in a different timezone.
  $str .= "<script>\n";
  $str .= "function adjustToday() {\n";
  $str .= "  var browser_today = new Date();\n";
  $str .= "  document.getElementById('today_link').href = '?$this->controlName='+browser_today.strftime('".DB_DATEFORMAT."');\n";
  $str .= "}\n";
  $str .= "adjustToday();\n";
  $str .= "</script>\n";

  return $str;
}

function toStringControl() {
    return $this->toString();
}

function _getWeekDayBefore($year, $month) {
  $weekday = date ( "w", mktime ( 2, 0, 0, $month, 1 - $this->weekStartDay, $year ) );
  return array(
    mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1 - $weekday, $year ),
    mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year ),
  mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $month + 1, 0, $year ),
  (1 - $weekday)
  );
}

function _genStyles() {
  $str = "<style>\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarHeader {". $this->mHeader ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDay {". $this->mDayCell  ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDaySelected {". $this->mDaySelected  ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDayWeekend {". $this->mDayWeekend ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDayHoliday {". $this->mDayHoliday ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDayHeader {". $this->mDayHeader ."}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarDayHeaderWeekend {". $this->mDayHeaderWeekend ."}\n";

  $str .= ".CalendarLinkWeekend {color: #999999;}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarLinkHoliday {color: #999999;}\n";
  $str .= ".CalendarLinkRecordsExist {color: #FF0000;}\n";
    $str .= "</style>\n";
    return $str;
}

// _getActiveDates returns an array of dates, for which entries exist for user.
// Type of entries (time or expenses) is determined by $this->highlight value.
function _getActiveDates($start, $end) {

  global $user;
  $user_id = $user->getActiveUser();

  $table = ($this->highlight == 'expenses') ? 'tt_expense_items' : 'tt_log';

  $mdb2 = getConnection();

  $start_date = date("Y-m-d", $start);
  $end_date = date("Y-m-d", $end);
  $sql = "SELECT date FROM $table WHERE date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date' AND user_id = $user_id AND status = 1";
  $res = $mdb2->query($sql);
  if (!is_a($res, 'PEAR_Error')) {
    while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
      $out[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date']));
    }
    return @$out;
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

}

How to disable past dates from the current date ? I tried few posts for similar question but was unable to achieve it, Below is what I tried

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a new date object and set it as minDate when you initialize the datepickers

```
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>

  var dateToday = new Date();
  var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
minDate: dateToday,
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
}
});
```